# Setting up a connection between a virtio and a mininet host

Tags: networking, network-programming, qemu, ethernet, mininet

I am trying to create an environment like this:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUOWb.png)

Right now I have a connection (eth1 -> eth2) and (eth3 -> eth4). (like the black arrows show). I also have a connection made between docker1 and docker2 in Mininet. How can I make a connection from eth2 to the docker1 in mininet and from docker2 to eth3 so that the packets will pass like the blue route shows it? I need to make the red connection somehow.

I tried using bridges but unfortunatelly right now the dock1 and dock2 are connected via one and one device can be connected to just one bridge. If I would add eth2 and eth3 to the bridge the packets wouldn't use the dock1 and dock2, so that is not a solution for me :/ .

Answer (score 0):

If you add eth2 and eth3 to the bridge that includes dock1 and dock2 the traffic should go pass dock1 and dock2 and later to eth4

Comment: It doesn't work this way unfortunatelly as I have written higher